# Calculus simplification

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

Could someone explain how this:

$\int(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}})dx$

becomes:

$\int(\sqrt{x+1})dx - \int(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}})dx$

Comment: What i am confused about especially is how the $\sqrt{x+1}$ ends up in the numerator of the first integral

Comment: Add and subtract $1$ from the numerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int(\sqrt{x+1})dx - \int(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}})dx$$
$$\int(\sqrt{x+1}) -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}dx$$

multiply both numerator and denominator by the same value $\sqrt  {(x+1)}$

$$\int  \frac {(x+1)-1}{\sqrt{x+1}}dx$$
$$\int  \frac x{\sqrt{x+1}}dx$$

Comment: I meant to write a response comment, but I answered my own question. It wasn't clear to me that you can just multiply the bottom and top by $\sqrt{x+1}$ and then cancel out. Thanks

Comment: Yes you can multiply numerator and denominator by the same value...@RileyPayung

Answer (score 0):

This does not come from integration by parts, but from substitution.  Let $u=x+1$ so that $du=dx$ and $x=u-1$.  Then

$$
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}} \ dx = \int \frac{u-1}{\sqrt{u}} \ du = \int \sqrt{u} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \ du.
$$
The last integral is 
$$
\int \sqrt{x+1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}} \ dx
$$
which is what you claim.  However, it is more easily done from the $u$ line since
$$
\int \sqrt{u} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \ du = \frac{2}{3}u^{3/2} - 2\sqrt{u} + C.  
$$
Sub back in $u=x+1$ and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It’s got nothing to do with the integral:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}} &= \frac{x+1-1}{\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&= \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&= \sqrt{x+1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}
\end{align}$$

Does that help?